# credential provider 64 bit on windows 7 pro

Tags: windows, winapi, winlogon

I have build a my own credential. I Installed it on 64 bit systems with Windows 7 home and it's ok. I tried to install it on 3 different machines with windows 7 64 pro and my provider is not shown.

I didn't know that there were differences in windows 7 version about credential provider.

I don't know what to try to solve problem. I tried to install a commercial Provider (aloaha, rohos) and they are ok, I tried to install microsoft samples ( 64 bit compiling) but they are not shown.

In windows 7 home premium 64 bit all is ok.

Comment: Please provide more info on how you built the CP

Answer (score 1):

Did you build it with the debug options?  If so you are probably missing debug runtime libraries on your other machines.

Here are some things for you to try

- Load into [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) see what libraries are linked to your CP.  Do this on both the machine where it loads ok and the machine where it doesn't load.  Don't be alarmed if it can't find some LogonUI related libraries, this is normal.
- Try looking at logonui  with WinDBG to make sure that it really the case that it doesn't load and there is not anything else is at play.  Look [here](http://www.paralint.com/blog/2011/03/26/how-to-debug-a-credential-provider-locally/) for instructions.
- The most comprehensive way to debug those is to use setup the debugging as described [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5372). Download the ZIP file and read the document especially the debugging section. It is pretty involved and you need to setup either a serial connection or do it with the VM.  But this way you will be able to set a breakpoint right when logonui starts up, you will be able to see the loading sequence of the credential providers and will see the exact error message when something fails.